# Powershell: How to read rows from CSV and if a column contains a string set variable(s) to each header of column that string is found in

Tags: powershell, csv, header

Let me try this again :)

What I have is a csv file that has a name and logonname column and then several other columns.  To make it easier I've called them colour names.   Each colour name may contain a "Yes" in that cell.

I have a powershell script that will only act upon one row at a time (a vendor tool).  So it will read  the value of Name and create an account, I write the logon name (samAccountName) into LogonName column beside that user.

This part works of the script works fine and uses import-csv and a Foreach($row in $csv) and writes logon name via $row.logonname

What I'm looking for is to add to my script so that it looks for "Yes" in any and all columns on the row of that user(Name) and if it finds a "Yes" then I'm sending an email with the a body containing Name LogonName and then headername: Yes  Which should look like this:

Name:John Smith
LogonName:jsmith 
Blue:Yes
Green:Yes

I have an input csv file "test.csv" that contains:

| Name | LogonName | Blue | Red | Green |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John Smith |  | Yes |  | Yes |

My working section is:

```
    $csv = import-Csv $testFile
    Foreach($row in $csv){
        $PersonName = $row.name
        if ($PersonName -eq $($nameVariable)){
            $row.LogonName = $($userVariable)
            $row.Password = $($passwordVariable)
        }       
     }
            
$csv | Export-CSV $testFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Sorry about all the confusion and poorly worded versions.

Thank you!

Comment: can you rephrase your question? im not understanding what you want.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? not what you just described .. what that is FOR?

Comment: Hi, sorry it was confusing I've edited it to hopefully make it clearer.
Thank you all.

Comment: Have I annoyed everyone with my re-writing this three times? :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a hint on how you can approach your script. Note that I'm using `ConvertFrom-Csv` instead of `Import-Csv` but it will work the same if you're reading a CSV and piping directly to `ForEach-Object`.

```
@'
Name,Blue,Red,Green
John,Yes,,Yes
Sam,,Yes,,
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv | ForEach-Object{
    $_.PSObject.Properties.Where({$_.Value}).foreach({
        "{0}: {1}" -f $_.Name, $_.Value
    })|Out-String
}
```

Output looks like this:

```
Name: John
Blue: Yes
Green: Yes

Name: Sam
Red: Yes
```

Now, its a bit hard to tell how exactly you wish the output too look. If you give us more details we may be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you for this!  I'm still new to Powershell and trying to decipher what all those symbols and short-cuts or psudo code means ie: @ is array? "{0:}: {1}
 are the elements of the array at position 0 and 1?

What I'm trying to achieve is two things:  

1) First part of my script will read the name from the row, then it will write the samAccountName to the appropriate column of that Row(This part is done)  
2) I want to then look for "Yes" in any columns of that Row and if found what is the header name so that it will look like:  
John Smith  
Blue:Yes  
Green:Yes

Answer (score 0):

Check each of the "columns" by name in a nested loop:

```
Import-Csv C:\scripts\test.csv |ForEach-Object {
  # Write the name (eg "John")
  Write-Host $_.Name

  foreach($color in 'Blue','Red','Green'){
    # For each color name, check if the corresponding column says "yes"
    if($_.$color -eq 'yes'){
      Write-Host "${color} = yes"
    }
  }
}
```